# Manualy prepare URL to post array data and other values

Tags: javascript, ajax, colorbox

I'm trying to send some values on url to post, but without success.

Initially i've do on jquery data, like:

```
data  : {cep:cep, peso:peso, valor:valor, dimensoes:dimensoes, ids : ids},
```

I this bring me some like this:

```
?cep=86062-020&peso=1000&valor=256.57&dimensoes%5B0%5D%5B0%5D%5Baltura%5D=29&dimensoes%5B0%5D%5B0%5D%5Blargura%5D=19&dimensoes%5B0%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcomprimento%5D=29&dimensoes%5B0%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalor%5D=256.57&dimensoes%5B0%5D%5B0%5D%5Bqtde%5D=1&dimensoes%5B0%5D%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=6765&ids%5B%5D=6765
```

Its ok.

But now, i need to send exactly this data and this format to load the result on colorbox, i'm using the colorbox js [here](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/), i've tryed this:

```
$.colorbox({iframe: false, height: '500px', href: 'carrinho/teste', width: '500px', data:{cep:cep, peso:peso, valor:valor, dimensoes:dimensoes, ids : ids}});
```

But not work.
I think might i have to make this URL on hand and pass just by href. But how?

Should i do all the process on hand or have some method on javasscript to do it?

Appreciate any answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert Object to query string manually, this is simple solution.

```
var data = {cep:cep, peso:peso, valor:valor, dimensoes:dimensoes, ids : ids};
var queryString = $.map(data, function(key, val){
    return key + "=" + val;
}).join("&");
```